# How to bundle a branch

Tags: git, git-bundle

I am new to git and have done following setup:

1. There is a repository on a server **S**.
2. I cloned it to my machine **A** and add some changes in a branch.
3. I just copied the repro from 2 to an usb-drive. Then walked over to machine **B**, which has no connection to **S** or **A**.
4. I then used this copied repro to make some changes to the branch (on machine **B**).
5. I read more about git -because there has to be some way to move my commits- and found **git bundle**.

Now I want move my commits from the **B** to **A**. Then from **A** to **S** but I think this will not be the problem.

I tried to follow [this text](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Bundling) and tried to call

```
 git bundle create commit.bundle L..H
```

,where L is the identifier for the last commit that is on both **A** and **B**, and H is the identifier for the last commit in **B**.

This gives:

```
fatal: Refusing to create empty bundle.
```

I clearly do not know how to do this right. I suppose it might have do something with me not using a bundle in my step 3 or that L and H are on a branch and I need to provid more information.

From [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) I know that:

```
git bundle will only package references that are shown by git show-ref
```

But I am not sure what this means. When I just type in git show-ref it gives a short list, that includes my commits H and L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the names for the commits given in `git show-ref` the problem disappears.